# how to show linked code snippet in issue directly

Tags: github

How to show linked code snippet in issue directly?
just like shown in the picture:

[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a documentation [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet/).

- Navigate to the code, click the line number to highlight the line
- To the left of the line, click on the three dots
- In the drop-down menu, click *Copy permalink*.
- Paste it in the conversation